# Mouse-down event not working on Canvas control in my wpf application

Tags: wpf, events, canvas, mvvm, restful-url

I am following MVVM for my wpf application project and creating different views/usercontrols for different tab control items,reading data from a Restful API.Why does my Mousedownclick event on the canvas control is not working for this view?Any help is highly appreciated.When I enter and click different canvas controls the text in the "textbox" should change accordingly.
Note:Even Mouseenter is also not working?

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="ISTE.Views.Resources"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ISTE.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button  Grid.Column="0" Name="go" Click="Button_Click" Margin="56,68,714,506" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"   >RIT Website</Button>
        <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1">
            <WebBrowser Height="600px"  x:Name="ritwebsite" Margin="117,0,254,0"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Canvas  Grid.Column="2" Height="400" Width="400">
            <Canvas Name="studyAbroad" MouseDown="studyAbroad_MouseDown" Height="132" Width="136" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="10" Background="Blue"/>
            <Canvas Name="studentServices" MouseDown="studyAbroad_MouseDown" Height="150" Width="154" Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="208" Background="SkyBlue"/>
            <Canvas Name="studentAmbassadors" MouseDown="studyAbroad_MouseDown" Height="150" Width="158" Canvas.Top="100" Canvas.Left="100" Background="DarkBlue"/>
        </Canvas>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" x:Name="res"><Run Text="ADJH"/><InlineUIContainer>
                <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="51" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="172" RenderTransformOrigin="0.924,8">
                    <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </TextBox.RenderTransform>
                </TextBox>
            </InlineUIContainer></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CS

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ISTE.ViewModels;
using ISTE.Models;

namespace ISTE.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Resources.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Resources : UserControl
    {
        ResourcesVM vm;
        public Resources()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new ResourcesVM();
            this.DataContext = vm;

            vm.GetData();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            this.ritwebsite.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.rit.edu"));
        }



        private void studyAbroad_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            {
                var b = sender as Canvas;
                var selected = b.Name;
                var resselected = b.Name.ToString();

                if (resselected == "studyAbroad")
                {
                    res.Text = "";
                    res.Text = vm.ItemData.studyAbroad.description;

                }
                else if (resselected == "studentServices")
                {
                    res.Text = "";
                    res.Text = vm.ItemData.studentServices.title;
                }
                else
                {
                    res.Text = "";
                    res.Text = vm.ItemData.studentAmbassadors.title;

                }


                /*   foreach (Place p in vm.ItemData.studyAbroad.places)
                   {
                       if (p.nameOfPlace == selected)
                       {
                           textBox.Text = "";
                           textBox.Text = p.description + "\n\n";
                           Console.WriteLine("places \t" + p.nameOfPlace);
                       }

                   }*/

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple enough, and actually has nothing to do with MVVM at all.

Look at the XAML definition, your `TextBlock` is taking up all available space of the 2nd column,  the canvases are beneath it so they can not respond to the mouse clicks.

Set a decent size to the `TextBlock` and move it to one of the corners can solve your problem.

Or you can recorder the Z-Order of the controls, first the TextBlock, then the canvases.

Comment: I don't believe I din't notice that,its working fine now Thanks :)